# webservices error org.json.jsonexception: Not a primitive array

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

Hallo I'm trying to connect to webservice and retrieve some data i want to take the items from webservice and treat them separately for example the descrition latitude and longitude separately and if i can put them to an array.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/xxx/GetLatLong";

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetLatLong";

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

private static final String URL = "//xxxx:xxx/xxxx/soap";        



@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    setContentView(textView);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int count = 0; count<array.length();count++){
            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(count);
            String description = obj.getString("Descritpion");
            String latidude = obj.getString("Latidute");
            String longidute = obj.getString("longidute");
        }


    }

    catch (Exception exception)

    {

        textView.setText(exception.toString());

    }


}
}
```

Comment: At this line `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);` Cast response to String, Now if this string is not a json or not a jsonarray string object it will throw the exception your getting.

Comment: now im getting error "value anyType of type java.lang.string cannot converted to jsonarray"

Comment: Can you check what string your server is returning, value anyType of type generally means the string is not a jsonstring.

Comment: [{"Description":"1","Latitude":0.369,"Longitude":1.258},{"Description":"2","Latitude":1.369,"Longitude":3.258},{"Description":"3","Latitude":2.369,"Longitude":4.258}]

This is the data from webservice

Comment: Json parser shows invalid json to the last one "Longitude":4.‌​258, i think some tab character or un-wanted character is append in b/w .2, Check here [Json Parser](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter)

Comment: i manualy changed the attribute of last langitude and still i get "org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject"


now its "[{"Description":"1","Latitude":0.369,"Longitude":1.258},{"Description":"2","Latitude":1.369,"Longitude":3.258},{"Description":"3","Latitude":2.369,"Longitude":2.258}]"

Comment: @jitainsharma Any help now ??